# Create requirements.txt without @ ~~ things

Tags: python, pip, conda, requirements.txt

I want to create requirements.txt using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command and copied to Google Drive to use in Google Colab but there is an error like:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work'
```

So, I opened the `requirements.txt`, there are strange things behind the module name started with `@ files:\\\~~~`

Here is the example.

`requirements.txt`

```
~~~
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab==2.2.6
jupyterlab-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_server_1594164409481/work
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/keras-applications_1594366238411/work
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
~~~
```

I installed these module using Anaconda and it stores in my virtual environment called 'TensorFlow'.

Is it okay delete the `@ files:\\\~~~` things behind the module name or what should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Conda, `pip freeze` is unlikely to work well/correctly.

Comment: yes it's okay to delete `@ files:\\\ `

Answer (score 7):

Yes, delete the `@ files:\\\` and for the future try `conda list -e > requirements.txt` instead of `pip`and then use the file in conda again so `conda create --name <env> --file requirements.txt`.